# How xpath read xml spaced elements?

Tags: java, xml

This is the xml, unfortunately anything of the XML is **NOT CHANGEABLE**:

`<allowance name ='' />
<allowance type ='' />
<allowance value='' />`

And i need to obtain only "allowance value" with xpath in java. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

This expression will return all 'allowance' elements that have the 'value' attribute:

```
//allowance[@value]
```

This will return just the value of "value":

```
//allowance[@value]/@value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try: /root//allowance[@value]